# jQuery AJAX page loading, DIV specific

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to bring in a specific DIV from a page called by the jQuery .load function.

This is the code i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('ul.navigation li a').click(function() {
        $('#content-wrap').fadeOut(500);

            var targetPage = $(this).attr('href')

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#content-wrap').load(targetPage, function() {
                $('#content-wrap').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });     
    return false;
    });

</script>
```

...and it works - but it calls the whole page, rather than a specific area...

Cheers!

Comment: Since this is a jQuery question rather than a WordPress question, I think it is better suited for StackOverflow and should be migrated. Agree/disagree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to load a page *fragment* rather than the whole page.  If you dig deeper into the documentation, you'll see you need to change your `targetPage` variable just slightly.

```
var targetPage = $(this).attr('href');
targetPage += " #content-wrap";
```

This will change the `targetPage` variable to something along the lines of `http://site.url #content-wrap` and will fetch the contents of the `#content-wrap` element rather than the whole page.

- See the Loading Page Fragments section of [the `.load()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more.

Comment: I see! I am just starting to get my head around jQuery - it seems i was looking at the wrong part to fix! Thank you : )